# Erro ModuleNotFoundError tentando usar Behave, Selenium e Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Reescrevendo o código de um exercício anterior, dessa vez usando Behave.
Problema é que não consigo nem começar pois não consigo fazer a importação com as funções necessárias.

Meu diretórios são esses:

```
-Curso_de_Selenium
    -todo_project
        -features
            -steps
                __init__.py
                todo.py
            __init__.py
            environment.py
            todo.feature
        -page_object
            __init__.py
            page_objects.py
        -pages
            __init__.py
            elements.py
            pages.py
        __init__.py
        behave.ini
```

Todos os **init**.py, na verdade, só estão lá pois li em algum lugar que eles são necessários para que o Python interprete o diretório como módulo mas, até agora, não ajudaram em nada.
Mas, talvez seja porque estão em branco...

Já tentei:

```
from Curso_de_Selenium.todo_project.pages.pages import pages
from todo_project.pages.pages import pages
from todo_project.pages import pages
```

Mas todos retornam o mesmo erro: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xxxxx'

Também tentei isso:

```
from C:.Users.lbsme.Desktop.Curso_de_Selenium.todo_project.pages.pages import pages
```

Mas esses 2 pontos em C: retornam um erro de sintaxe.

Vi muita gente passando por essa situação mas todos estavam usando o pytest então as soluções deles não me serviram.
Não sei mais o que tentar.